# Retrieve value of CheckBox from ListView and assign to Object in array list

Tags: android, android-edittext, listener, android-checkbox

I have an app that currently displays a list of names in a ListView. Each item in the ListView consists of a CheckBox and an EditText.

The list of names is provided by an ArrayList of 'Prospects' objects

When the user selects the CheckBox I want to return the state of this check box and assign it the Propsects object at the relevant position in the ArrayList so it can be saved for use the next time the app is opened (this will be done using CSV).

I'm struggling with the correct listener to use to do this as this is my first attempt at Android programming. I've been unable to find any examples that match what i'm trying to achieve or if I have i've not understood them!.

Any help would be appreciated!

My code is as follows:

```
package com.veetox.networkmarketingmanager;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewConfiguration;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.veetox.networkmarketingmanager.data.Prospects;
import com.veetox.networkmarketingmanager.helper.FileHelper;
import com.veetox.networkmarketingmanager.helper.ProspectListAdapter;
import com.veetox.networkmarketingmanager.helper.ProspectViewHolder;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    public static ArrayList<Prospects> prospectList = new ArrayList<>();
    Resources res;
    FileHelper fileHelper = new FileHelper(this);
    ListView prospectsListEntry;
    CheckBox prospectsCheckBox;
    EditText prospectsEditText;
    ProspectListAdapter pla;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        prospectsCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pr_checkBox);
        prospectsEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pr_name);

        res = getResources();

        createProspectList();

        prospectsListEntry.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View item, int position, long id)
            {
                //Create new Prospect cloning Prospect at row in ItemList that was clicked
                Prospects prospect = pla.getItem(position);

                //Change the state of contacted from true to false or vice versa
                prospect.toggleContacted();

                //Create a ProspectViewHolder to hold the view for the row clicked
                ProspectViewHolder viewHolder = (ProspectViewHolder) item.getTag();
                viewHolder.getCheckBox().setChecked(prospect.isChecked());

                prospectList.get(position) ;
                pla.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });



    }

    public void testProspects(View view)
    {
        prospectList = fileHelper.testProspects();
        pla.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }


    public void createProspectList()
    {
        fileHelper = new FileHelper(this);

        //Comment before testing
        //prospectList = fileHelper.loadProspects();

        //Uncomment for testing
        prospectList = fileHelper.testProspects();

        //Create the list
        pla = new ProspectListAdapter(this, R.layout.prospects_list_layout, prospectList);
        prospectsListEntry = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.prospects_list);
        prospectsListEntry.setAdapter(pla);

    }
}

package com.veetox.networkmarketingmanager.helper;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.veetox.networkmarketingmanager.MainActivity;
import com.veetox.networkmarketingmanager.R;
import com.veetox.networkmarketingmanager.data.Prospects;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Matt on 29/09/2016.
 */

public class ProspectListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Prospects>
{

    private Context context;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private ArrayList<Prospects> prospect;



    public ProspectListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Prospects> prospect)
    {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, prospect);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.prospect = prospect;

    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return prospect.size();
    }


    public Prospects getItem(int position)
    {
        return prospect.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            v = vi.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        }

        Prospects prospects = prospect.get(position);

        if (prospects != null)
        {
            TextView prname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pr_name);
            CheckBox complete = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.pr_checkBox);


            if (prname != null)
            {
                prname.setText(prospects.getName());
            }

            if (complete != null)
            {
                complete.setChecked(prospects.isChecked());
            }


        }




        return v;
    }



}

package com.veetox.networkmarketingmanager.data;


/**
 * A Prospective customer
 */

public class Prospects
{
    private String prospectname;
    private boolean contacted;
    private String stringContacted;

    public Prospects(String aName, boolean contacted)
    {
        prospectname = aName;
        this.contacted = contacted;
    }

    public Prospects(String aName, String contacted)
    {
        prospectname = aName;
        this.stringContacted = contacted;
    }

    public Prospects(String aName)
    {
        prospectname = aName;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return prospectname;
    }

    public boolean isChecked()
    {
        return contacted;
    }

    public void setName (String aName)
    {
        prospectname = aName;
    }

    public void setContacted(boolean contacted)
    {
        this.contacted = contacted;
    }

    public void toggleContacted()
    {
        if (contacted)
        {
            contacted = false;
        }
        else
        {
            contacted = true;
        }
    }




}

package com.veetox.networkmarketingmanager.helper;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.veetox.networkmarketingmanager.data.Prospects;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;


/**
 * Created by Matt on 28/09/2016.
 */

public final class FileHelper
{
    Context context;


   public FileHelper(Context aContext)
   {
       context = aContext;




   }


    public void saveProspects(ArrayList<Prospects> prospects)
    {

        ArrayList<Prospects> p = prospects;

        BufferedWriter bufferedFileWriter = null;


        try
        {
            File aFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "prospects.csv");
            aFile.createNewFile();

            bufferedFileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(aFile));

            for (Prospects eachProspect : p)
            {
                bufferedFileWriter.write(eachProspect.getName());
                bufferedFileWriter.write(",");
                bufferedFileWriter.write(String.valueOf(eachProspect.isChecked()));
                bufferedFileWriter.newLine();
            }


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Toast.makeText(context, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                bufferedFileWriter.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //Toast.makeText(context, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }

    public ArrayList<Prospects> loadProspects()
    {
        ArrayList<Prospects> prospectsList = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner bufferedScanner = null;
        Scanner lineScanner = null;



            try
            {
                File aFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "prospects.csv");
                bufferedScanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aFile)));
                while (bufferedScanner.hasNextLine())
                {
                    lineScanner = new Scanner(bufferedScanner.nextLine());
                    lineScanner.useDelimiter(",");
                    String prospect = lineScanner.next();
                    String contacted = lineScanner.next();

                    Prospects aProspect = new Prospects(prospect, contacted);
                    prospectsList.add(aProspect);

                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //Toast.makeText(context, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    bufferedScanner.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    //Toast.makeText(context, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
                return prospectsList;
            }

        public ArrayList<Prospects> testProspects()
        {
            ArrayList<Prospects> p = new ArrayList<>();

            Prospects q = new Prospects("Matt Lee", true);
            Prospects r = new Prospects("Rosemary Watson", false);
            Prospects s = new Prospects("Joe Bloggs", false);
            Prospects t = new Prospects("Ronny Corbit", false);
            Prospects u = new Prospects("Mr Man", false);
            Prospects v = new Prospects("Mr Bond", true);
            Prospects w = new Prospects("Mr Blobby", true);
            Prospects x = new Prospects("Mary Rose", false);
            Prospects y = new Prospects("Jane Doe", false);
            Prospects z = new Prospects("Lucy Sanders", false);

            p.add(q);
            p.add(r);
            p.add(s);
            p.add(t);
            p.add(u);
            p.add(v);
            p.add(w);
            p.add(x);
            p.add(y);
            p.add(z);

            return p;
        }



}
```

Comment: you need to move your checkbox check(checked/notChecked) in adapter. you'll need ItemId to access  and retrive the clicked item in ListView.

Comment: Thank you! Once I moved my listeners into my adapter my issue was sorted.

Comment: please vote up and mark this answer (below) as accepted. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your checkbox check(checked/notChecked) in adapter. you'll need ItemId to access and retrive the clicked item in ListView.